# Method chaining and promises issue in Angular app with regards to returning a compared and updated array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, method-chaining

I am trying to filter/match a list of returned IDs to a list of JSON data records, but I am struggling with (I believe) my promises and method chaining.

**I can get the functions to work, except for when I add step 3 below.** Then it resolves without the matching data (**the function does carry on and eventually return the correct matching data, but by that time my method has already completed**).

This is how it is supposed to work:

1. (getCompanyBrandProfileIDs) First my method gets a brandProfileID linked to the current user.
2. (getBrandProfiles) Then it takes the brandProfileID and get all brandProfiles linked to the specific brandProfile.
3. (getKeywordProfiles) Then it **SHOULD** take the returned brandProfiles, and get the matching keywordProfile for each brandProfile. It is an array of objects containing a brand_profile_id and and id.

**This is my main method:**

```
this.getCompanyBrandProfileIDs = function () {

  var brandProfileIDsToReturn = $q.defer();

  GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {

      console.log(brandProfileID);

      getBrandProfiles(brandProfileID).then(function (brandProfiles) {

          console.log(JSON.stringify(brandProfiles));

          var keywordProfilesArray = [];

          getKeywordProfiles(brandProfiles).then(function (keywordProfiles) {

              keywordProfilesArray = keywordProfiles;

              console.log(JSON.stringify(keywordProfilesArray));

              //brandProfileIDsToReturn.resolve(keywordProfilesArray);

          });

          brandProfileIDsToReturn.resolve(keywordProfilesArray);

      });

  });

  return brandProfileIDsToReturn.promise;

};
```

**This is the getBrandProfiles method:**

```
function getBrandProfiles(brandProfileID) {

  var getBrandProfilesLinkedToCompany = $q.defer();

  pullSocialMediaData('keyword_profile_brand_profiles.json?brand_profile_id=' + brandProfileID).then(function (brandProfiles) {

      var brandProfilesArray = [];

      brandProfiles.forEach(function (profile) {

          brandProfilesArray.push({ id: profile.id, name: profile.name });

      });

      getBrandProfilesLinkedToCompany.resolve(brandProfilesArray);

  });

  return getBrandProfilesLinkedToCompany.promise;
```

}

**This is the getKeywordProfiles method:**

```
function getKeywordProfiles(brandProfiles) {

      var keywordProfilesToReturn = $q.defer();

      var brandProfilesArray = brandProfiles;

      var array = [];

      brandProfilesArray.forEach(function (profile) {
          findKeywordProfile(profile.id).then(function (keywordID) {

              array.push(keywordID);
          });
          keywordProfilesToReturn.resolve(array);
      })

      return keywordProfilesToReturn.promise;

  }
```

**This is a helper method for getKeywordProfiles:**

```
function findKeywordProfile(brandProfileID) {

  var keywordProfileID = $q.defer();

  pullSocialMediaData('list_keyword_profiles.json').then(function (data) {

      var keywordProfileInstance = data.filter(function (keyword) {
          return keyword.brand_profile_id === brandProfileID;
      });

      keywordProfileID.resolve(keywordProfileInstance[0].id);

  });

  return keywordProfileID.promise;
}
```

I would appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resolving the `brandProfileIDsToReturn` too soon. In this code: when you resolve the promise the `then` callback will not have been called, so `keywordProfilesArray` is guaranteed to be empty.

```
this.getCompanyBrandProfileIDs = function () {
  var brandProfileIDsToReturn = $q.defer();
  GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {
      console.log(brandProfileID);
      getBrandProfiles(brandProfileID).then(function (brandProfiles) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(brandProfiles));
          var keywordProfilesArray = [];
          getKeywordProfiles(brandProfiles).then(function (keywordProfiles) {
              keywordProfilesArray = keywordProfiles;
              console.log(JSON.stringify(keywordProfilesArray));
              //brandProfileIDsToReturn.resolve(keywordProfilesArray);
          });
          brandProfileIDsToReturn.resolve(keywordProfilesArray);
      });
  });
  return brandProfileIDsToReturn.promise;
};
```

Simply moving the `resolve()` call inside the `then` callback should fix it and in fact you have that line commented out, so uncomment it and remove the other resolve:

```
this.getCompanyBrandProfileIDs = function () {
  var brandProfileIDsToReturn = $q.defer();
  GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {
      console.log(brandProfileID);
      getBrandProfiles(brandProfileID).then(function (brandProfiles) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(brandProfiles));
          var keywordProfilesArray = [];
          getKeywordProfiles(brandProfiles).then(function (keywordProfiles) {
              keywordProfilesArray = keywordProfiles;
              console.log(JSON.stringify(keywordProfilesArray));
              brandProfileIDsToReturn.resolve(keywordProfilesArray);
          });
      });
  });
  return brandProfileIDsToReturn.promise;
};
```

However you can probably simplify the code a lot if you stop using `$q.defer()`. Your functions already return promises so just return the promises they use and stop trying to create additional promises. I think this is equivalent to the previous code except it returns the promises directly, and I removed the log messages, and that means the getKeywordProfiles call simplifies down to a callback that just calls the function so you can pass the function directly:

```
this.getCompanyBrandProfileIDs = function () {
  return GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {
      return getBrandProfiles(brandProfileID).then(getKeywordProfiles);
      });
  });
};
```

and then you can simplify it further by extracting the inner `.then`:

```
this.getCompanyBrandProfileIDs = function () {
  return GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID()
  .then(getBrandProfiles)
  .then(getKeywordProfiles);
};
```

The `getKeywordProfiles()` function also needs to avoid resolving its promise until all of the `findKeywordProfile()` calls have resolved. Return a promise for the array of promises and when they resolve the promise will complete to an array of values:

```
function getKeywordProfiles(brandProfilesArray) {
      var array = [];
      brandProfilesArray.forEach(function (profile) {
          array.push(findKeywordProfile(profile.id));
      })
      return $q.all(array);
  }
```

To clarify my comments about `$q`, there are some cases where you need to create a promise from scratch using it, but they're fairly uncommon. Anything that happens asynchronously in Angular already returns a promise, and the great thing about promises is that they chain together, so when you have one promise calling `.then()` or `.catch()` will return a new one. Also the `.then()` callback can either return a value which resolves the new promise, or can return a promise which will only resolve the new promise when it, itself resolves. So just keep chaining the `.then()` calls together and each will wait for the previous one to complete.

`$q` is still useful though: `$q.all()` if you want to wait for a bunch of promises to all resolve, `$q.race()` if you have a bunch of promises and only one needs to resolve, `$q.resolve(value)` can also be useful as sometimes you just want a promise that will resolve immediately so you can hang a chain of other async functions off it.

Also it is safe to keep a promise around even long after it has resolved and you can still call `.then()` on it: this is useful if you have asynchronous initialisation code and events that may or may not be triggered before the initialisation has completed. No need to do `if(isInitialised)` when you can just do `initPromise.then(...)`

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe how much you simplified the code. Thank you! Can you perhaps give me insight re not using $q? Does Angular manage the promises automatically?

Comment: I added some more comments about `$q` but search around and there are some great articles on how to use promises effectively.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight - it is really valuable!

Answer (score 1):

In `getKeywordProfiles` function you need resolve it when array loop finished.

```
  function getKeywordProfiles(brandProfiles) {

      var keywordProfilesToReturn = $q.defer();

      var brandProfilesArray = brandProfiles;

      var array = [];

      brandProfilesArray.forEach(function (profile) {
          findKeywordProfile(profile.id).then(function (keywordID) {

              array.push(keywordID);
          });
          //--
          //keywordProfilesToReturn.resolve(array);
      })
      //++
      keywordProfilesToReturn.resolve(array);
      return keywordProfilesToReturn.promise;
  }
```

**Info**: I think you need to create an profileIdArray push all brandProfileID and send to your findKeywordProfile function. It will be more useful.

Comment: Thank you for the help - I really appreciate it!